# Manwha where a blonde girl and one of the Male Leads are in a cave and the girl asks the ML to die for her

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don't remember much but there's a blond girl (possibly named Charlotte) who is supposed to be gentle and everything and 3 guys are completely in love with her. There is another girl (the Main Character) who is badass and knows how to fight with a sword, and she can see that the blond girl is pretending to be kind.

I don't remember that much apart from a really specific scene: the blond girl and one of the male leads (the best knight of the crown prince or something like that) are cornered at the top of a cliff by monsters and they have to jump. They end up in a cave and the guy is hurt, after some time, some monsters appear and the blond girl panics and asks the hurt guy to save her even if he has to die. But then, the MC comes on top of them and saves the day. I think the monsters were things like mushrooms.

After all of this the blond girl wants to be treated first because she has a little scratch on her leg and doesn't want a scar because she's a lady and blabla while the guy is like: ok I just nearly died to save you, I'm hurt and that's how you thank me?

If I'm not mistaken the MC is from another world and she is the one who wrote the story she ended up in. At the beginning of the story we know that the MC is the writer of the story and she is the villainess of the story who is supposed to die by the hand of the crown prince. There is a moment where the crown prince confessed is love to the blond girl in public and the MC (the author) is disgusted by the cheesy lines she wrote.

And after I don't remember, before either! Sorry if I made mistakes I'm french, and thank you if you can help me find the name of this manwha because it's driving me crazy !

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour was the main character's hair?

Comment: Black if I remember well

Comment: Do you remember how the MC fights? With swords? Magic? Some other weapon?

Comment: Sword and maybe magic but not sure about that

Comment: Do you remember what year you read this, and about how many chapters there were? Do you have any idea where this specific scene takes place in the story? (e.g. is it within the first 10 chapters? 30? 100?)

Comment: I read it between the end of 2021 and 3 months ago, and I'm not sure but I'd say it wasn't more than 50 chapters maybe ? And the scene take place between 30 and 50 chapters maybe ? I'm really not sure about that really sorry

Comment: Any idea what they were doing on the cliff before they had to jump off? Were they there for any special reason, or were they chased there, or anything like that?

Comment: I don't sorry I just remember that they were chased and had to jump bit nothing before that sorry

Comment: I just remembered that at the begging of the story we know that the MC is the writer of the story and she is the villainess of the story who is supposed to die by the hand of the crown prince. There is a moment where the crown prince confessed is love to the blond girl in public and the MC (the author) is disgusted by the cheesey lines she wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[The Villainess's Maker](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-villainesss-maker)*.

> Yoon Haneul has always been a pushover, someone who would never say no. Then one day, she opens her eyes and realizes that she has become Aila Mertensia, **the antagonist of a novel she had written ten years ago**. Haneul is content to live the life of a rich couch potato and binge-read novels. But to her dismay, she soon finds herself stuck in a time loop where her day repeats endlessly, and the only way to escape the loop is to act like Aila Mertensia!

The first chapter indeed includes the main character reacting to lines she wrote:

[image: Cringe]

The blonde in question is indeed named Charlotte, and is the heroine of the original novel, and loved by everyone.

The scene from the question takes place between chapters 45 and 49, and basically goes exactly as described. Toadstool-like monsters attack a group of knights; Charlotte is separated and only has a single defender who is severely wounded, and acts very un-angellike while in distress.

[image: Die for me] [image]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tag combination `Author/s`, `prince/s`, `Villainess/es`.

Comment: Oh my god thank you !! I was going crazy remembering just this scene thank you !!